# VBA to Copy Range on Year to Date basis

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with three columns. Column C:C has all calendar dates, N:N contains Data 1 and R:R Data 2.

The macro I am trying to write should check dates in Column C to find dates that are (EDIT) less than today and copy data of Column R:R to Column N:N.

Does this make sense? I have a feeling it's a super basic thing, but oh well, I spent one hour Googling without success.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59Ess.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/looping-through-a-range-of-cells) and [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset)

Comment: "The macro I am trying to write should evaluate Column A to find dates that are...." I got a feeling you are missing a part of your question. Have a look at [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit your question accordingly =)

Comment: Hi Zan - What do you mean by evaluate? you need to specify your requirement exactly and as you mentioned this would be a simple one. Thanks.

Comment: Hi everyone. Thanks for feedback so far. I have added some more information and an actual example. Thanks also for linking articles!

Comment: After copying where the data needs to be pasted? in a new workbook or worksheets ? etc. etc. provide the requirements clearly in order to get quick assistance. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel a date is just the number of days which starts counting from January 1st 1900. So January 1, 1900 is number 1. With this in mind, it is very easy to calculate with dates. Hours and minutes are fractions.

This sub should do the job:

```
Sub CopyData()
    For i = 1 To 100
        If Cells(i, 3) < DateTime.Date Then
            Cells(i, 14) = Cells(i, 18)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Replace the number 100 with the amount of lines you have or with some logic to count the number of lines.
Succes.

Comment: Thanks! How about if the amount of rows isn't fixed? For example, I have 365 rows for each date and want to copy only the rows until the one that contains todays' date?

Comment: `januaryFirst = DateTime.DateSerial(Year(DateTime.Date), 1, 1)
daysOfYear = DateDiff(&#34;d&#34;, januaryFirst, DateTime.Date) + 1` Replace '100' by daysOfYear.